# Combinar celdas de 1 o mas columnas con jsPDF

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Estimados estoy mostrando cierta información obtenida de mi bd de datos en una tabla , utilizando jsPDF-Autotable.

Utilizando el siguiente código.

```
reporte_proformas(cabeceradetpfr,detpfr){
 const tableData1 = []
        const tableData2 = []
        const headers1 = ['Codigo','Descripcion', 'Cantidad', 'Desc(%)','Impto.','VVU.','VV-Desc.']
       detpfr.forEach(item => {
            if(item.Grupo == 'REP'){
                const rowData = [
                    item.Grupo,
                    item.Prod,
                    item.CANTIDAD,
                    item.DESCUENTO_I,
                    item.IMPUESTO,
                    item.PRECIO,
                    item.VV_DESC
                ]
                tableData1.push(rowData)
            }else{
                const rowData2 = [
                    item.Grupo,
                    item.Prod,
                    item.CANTIDAD,
                    item.DESCUENTO_I,
                    item.IMPUESTO,
                    item.PRECIO,
                    item.VV_DESC
                ]
                tableData2.push(rowData2)
            }
        })  
        autoTable(doc,{
            head: [headers1],
            body: tableData1,
            theme: 'grid',
            styles: {
                fontSize: 8,
                cellWidth: 'wrap'
            },
            columnStyles:{
                1:{cellWidth:95}
            },
            headStyles :{fillColor : [ 243, 30, 13]},
            //autoSize: true,
            margin:{top:70,left:2}
            
            
        })
        //Division
       // doc.setLineWidth(0.5);
        //doc.line(2, 80, 205, 80);
        //TABLA 2
        autoTable(doc,{
            head: [headers1],
            body: tableData2,
            theme: 'grid',
            styles: {
                fontSize: 8,
                cellWidth: 'wrap'
            },
            columnStyles:{
                1:{cellWidth:95}
            },
            headStyles :{fillColor : [ 243, 30, 13]},
            //autoSize: true,
            margin:{top:70,left:2}
            
        })

        //
        //doc.autoPrint(({variant: 'non-conform'}))
        return doc.save('Proforma'+' '+ cabeceradetpfr.PFR+'.pdf')
```

}

El resultado es el siguiente :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero como puedo combinar la primera columna par obtener el siguiente resultado.
Alguna sugerencia o que debo de considerar en el codigo mostrado.
Gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]